OPPO CPH series PVRSRVBridgeCall failed issue
  E  :539: PVRSRVBridgeCall: Bridge call failed. sBridgePackage.ui32BridgeID:0x6, Function ID:0x2a errno 22 (Invalid argument).
2024-11-21 17:27:06.871 19144-19286 IMGSRV                  jrm.org.upn                          E  :554: PVRSRVBridgeCall: fd 212 read as /proc/self/fd/212 pointing to /dev/dri/renderD128.
2024-11-21 17:27:06.871 19144-19286 IMGSRV                  jrm.org.upn                          E  :4410: BridgeDevmemIntReserveRange2: BridgeCall failed
2024-11-21 17:27:06.871 19144-19286 IMGSRV                  jrm.org.upn                          E  :539: PVRSRVBridgeCall: Bridge call failed. sBridgePackage.ui32BridgeID:0x6, Function ID:0x2c errno 22 (Invalid argument).
2024-11-21 17:27:06.871 19144-19286 IMGSRV                  jrm.org.upn                          E  :554: PVRSRVBridgeCall: fd 212 read as /proc/self/fd/212 pointing to /dev/dri/renderD128.
2024-11-21 17:27:06.871 19144-19286 IMGSRV                  jrm.org.upn                          E  :4601: BridgeDevmemIntMapPMR2: BridgeCall failed
2024-11-21 17:27:06.873 19144-30602 IMGSRV                  jrm.org.upn                          E  :539: PVRSRVBridgeCall: Bridge call failed. sBridgePackage.ui32BridgeID:0x6, Function ID:0x2b errno 22 (Invalid argument).
2024-11-21 17:27:06.873 19144-30602 IMGSRV                  jrm.org.upn                          E  :554: PVRSRVBridgeCall: fd 212 read as /proc/self/fd/212 pointing to /dev/dri/renderD128.
2024-11-21 17:27:06.873 19144-30602 IMGSRV                  jrm.org.upn                          E  :4502: BridgeDevmemIntUnreserveRange2: BridgeCall failed
2024-11-21 17:27:06.873 19144-30602 IMGSRV                  jrm.org.upn                          E  :282: pfnBridgeCall() failed (PVRSRV_ERROR_BRIDGE_CALL_FAILED) in _ResourceCleanupWrapper()
2024-11-21 17:27:06.873 19144-30602 IMGSRV                  jrm.org.upn                          E  :171: PVRSRVWaitForCondition-pfnCallback() failed (PVRSRV_ERROR_BRIDGE_CALL_FAILED) in WaitForCondition()
2024-11-21 17:27:06.893 19144-19286 IMGSRV                  jrm.org.upn                          E  :539: PVRSRVBridgeCall: Bridge call failed. sBridgePackage.ui32BridgeID:0x6, Function ID:0x2a errno 22 (Invalid argument).
2024-11-21 17:27:06.893 19144-19286 IMGSRV                  jrm.org.upn                          E  :554: PVRSRVBridgeCall: fd 212 read as /proc/self/fd/212 pointing to /dev/dri/renderD128.
2024-11-21 17:27:06.893 19144-19286 IMGSRV                  jrm.org.upn                          E  :4410: BridgeDevmemIntReserveRange2: BridgeCall failed
2024-11-21 17:27:06.893 19144-19286 IMGSRV                  jrm.org.upn                          E  :539: PVRSRVBridgeCall: Bridge call failed. sBridgePackage.ui32BridgeID:0x6, Function ID:0x2c errno 22 (Invalid argument).
2024-11-21 17:27:06.893 19144-19286 IMGSRV                  jrm.org.upn                          E  :554: PVRSRVBridgeCall: fd 212 read as /proc/self/fd/212 pointing to /dev/dri/renderD128.
2024-11-21 17:27:06.893 19144-19286 IMGSRV                  jrm.org.upn                          E  :4601: BridgeDevmemIntMapPMR2: BridgeCall failed
2024-11-21 17:27:06.895 19144-30602 IMGSRV                  jrm.org.upn                          E  :539: PVRSRVBridgeCall: Bridge call failed. sBridgePackage.ui32BridgeID:0x6, Function ID:0x2b errno 22 (Invalid argument).
2024-11-21 17:27:06.895 19144-30602 IMGSRV                  jrm.org.upn                          E  :554: PVRSRVBridgeCall: fd 212 read as /proc/self/fd/212 pointing to /dev/dri/renderD128.
2024-11-21 17:27:06.895 19144-30602 IMGSRV                  jrm.org.upn                          E  :4502: BridgeDevmemIntUnreserveRange2: BridgeCall failed

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC" />


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />


    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>



    <application
        android:name=".application.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MySplashScreen"
        tools:targetApi="31">


        <!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.flag.OPTIMIZE_INSTALLATION"
            android:value="true" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.flag.OPTIMIZE_AD_LOADING"
            android:value="true" />

        <property
            android:name="android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG"
            android:resource="@xml/gma_ad_services_config"
            tools:replace="android:resource" />


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MySplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="upn.org.in" />
                <data android:host="www.upn.org.in" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".AllowStaffLoginActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.UPN_Final"/>

        <service
            android:name=".background.service.MyNotificationService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync"
            android:label="@string/service_label"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".background.service.PushNotificationService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name=".background.repo.NotificationActionReceiver" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".sections.premium.repo.PremiumAlarmReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".sections.premium.repo.PremiumAlarmService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="specialUse" />

        <receiver android:name=".background.service.RestartReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>

The above is my Android Manifest.xml
I am facing an issue on my Oppo F17 Pro (CPH series) while running my Jetpack Compose app in Android Studio. The logs show repeated errors like:
This seems to be related to the PowerVR GPU driver (IMGSRV) and occurs during rendering tasks, particularly with Jetpack Compose's UI elements. The issue doesn't appear on other devices, only on the Oppo F17 Pro.
I’ve tried updating the device firmware, disabling hardware acceleration, and using alternative renderers (Skia/OpenGL), but the error persists. It might be a compatibility issue between the GPU driver and modern rendering pipelines.
How can I prevent this error, especially when the GPU seems to fail during intensive UI operations? Any workaround or solution to handle GPU-related rendering failures on such devices would be appreciated.

Is your Jetpack Compose app still displayed correctly, despite the error? Because if it does, I think you should not worry too much about this.
